# How to properly use recursion with Json data and structure it

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, recursion

I am working on a code, that fetches Json data from mssql server in node app.
Scenario is:

1. I fetch list of managers on first API call based on Username of head-manager, each manager has a Username.
2. Based on that Username I run a recursive function all to iterate through database to fetch their sub-managers. and so on.

Endgoal: To return collective data into JSON response
My desired output should be:

```
{
Username:"Head-manager Username",
children:[
   {
    Username:"manager Username",
    children:[{
     {
       Username:"Sub-manager Username",
       children:[]}
   }]
.
.
.
}
]

}
```

My code:

```
function getTreeData(dataset, newObj = {}) {
  return dataset.map(async (employee, index) => {
    let query = `SELECT [Username], [First Name], [Last Name] FROM TBL_M_FACT_EMPLOYEE_CENTRAL_ACTIVE WHERE [Reporting Manager User Sys ID] = '${employee.Username}'`;

    let data = await config.sequelize.query(query, {
      type: config.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    });


    newObj={...newObj,data}
  

      console.log("--------------------------");
      console.log(query);
      // console.log(data);
      console.log(newObj)

      console.log("--------------------------");
    if(data.length === 0){
      return newObj
    }else{
      getTreeData(data);
    }
    
  });

}

authRouter.get("/getEmployeeData", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("Initi");
    let sql_Query = `SELECT [Username], [First Name], [Last Name] FROM TBL_M_FACT_EMPLOYEE_CENTRAL_ACTIVE WHERE [Reporting Manager User Sys ID] = 'T502217'`;
    let result = await config.sequelize.query(sql_Query, {
      type: config.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    });

    console.log("Loop started Finally");

    getTreeData(result);

    res.status(200).json({
      username: "T502217",
      chilren: result,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok.  And are you having problems?  Does this code not do what you expect?

Comment: No, I am not even sure if my code is right

Comment: Please read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  I don't know if your code is right without being able to run it.  And [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO.  This is a common problem.

Comment: I was a little hasty there.  I can definitely see several reasons why this code *won't* work.  You don't return anything from your recursive call, only from your base call.  And you map asynchronous calls without using `Promise.all` or some other way to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does something similar.  The snippet includes a dummy DB that will return an array of `{id, first, last}` objects based on a fixed array of such objects that also have `manager` properties.  (This is really a dummy, essentially looking for `'<some id>'` in your query string and finding all the records that have that id for their manager.  It doesn't understand the rest of your SQL.)

Our function is `getTreeData`  It takes a manager and returns the tree of reports for that manager.  It defaults its parameter to `''` so that if we don't supply anything, it will get all those without a manager (presumably only the top boss.)

Although we kept your `getTreeData` name here, notice that it's actually a misnomer.  It doesn't return a tree but an entire forest.

The remaining code is what I would expect inside your route.  I haven't tried to rewrite that.  Essentially the call `getTreeData ()` will return a promise for an array of top-level members.  You may have to adjust for your fixed input of `'T502217'`.

```js
const getTreeData = async (id = '') =>
  db .query (`SELECT id, first, last FROM ACTIVE_EMPLOYEES WHERE manager = '${id}'`).
    then (reports => Promise .all (
      reports .map (report => getTreeData (report.id) .then (children => ({...report, children})))
    ))
  
getTreeData ()
  .then (ceos => ceos [0]) // there can be only one! :-)
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// dummy database, only reponds to one parameterized query
const db = (() => {
  const activeEmployees = [
    {id: 'A23423', first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone', manager: 'C12345'},
    {id: 'A23571', first: 'Betty', last: 'Rubble', manager: 'A98765'},
    {id: 'A34567', first: 'Barney', last: 'Rubble', manager: 'C24680'},
    {id: 'A98765', first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone', manager: 'C12345'},
    {id: 'C12345', first: 'Pebbles', last: 'Flintstone', manager: ''}, // the CEO!
    {id: 'C24680', first: 'BamBam', last: 'Rubble', manager: 'A98765'},
    {id: 'P13579', first: 'Dino', last: 'Flintstone', manager: 'C12345'},
  ]
  return {
    // ex: "SELECT id, first, last FROM ACTIVE_EMPLOYEES WHERE manager = '<some id>'" 
    query: async (str, id = str .match (/'([^']*)'/) [1]) =>
      Promise .resolve (
        activeEmployees .filter (({manager}) => manager == id) .map (({id, first, last}) => ({id, first, last}))
      )
  }
})()
</script>
```

There's nothing interesting the the `db` code, just something to make this demonstrable.  The idea is that this:

```js
db .query (`SELECT id, first, last from ACTIVE_EMPLOYEES WHERE manager = 'A98765'`)
```

will return a promise that resolves with data that looks like this:

```js
[
  {id: "A23571", first: "Betty", last: "Rubble"}, 
  {id: "C24680", first: "BamBam", last: "Rubble"}
]
```

because Betty and BamBam have Wilma (id `A98765`) as their manager.